# SSH -i command not found

Tags: ssh

I want a run a script located on server 2 from server 1.

I am running this command line on server 1:

> /home/user_x/keys.pem -t -t ec2-user@10.10.10.10 sudo
>   /home/gather/scripts/startTomcat6_nonroot.sh

Which give me this error:

> /home/user_y/tomcat/bin/startup.sh: line 11: uname: command not found

Here is the snippet of this file on server 2 containing the uname command:

```
#!/bin/sh
os400=false
darwin=false
#line bellow is number 11, the one failing
case "`uname`" in
CYGWIN*) cygwin=true;;
OS400*) os400=true;;
Darwin*) darwin=true;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause for this is a `$PATH` on server 2 that doesn't include `uname`; sanity check the environment variables when logged in under that user.

Comment: yes I think is the issue, do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @JeromeAnsia It depends completely on the system - you'll need to review the files that are manipulating `$PATH` to find whatever's breaking it and fix it.  Examining what's in it will probably offer a clue.

Comment: K thank you Shane, a weird think also if I do "ssh -i /home/userx/keys.pem -t -t ec2-user@10.100.2.151 'uname'", it's working without trouble (got Linux)

Comment: @JeromeAnsia How about if you do `sudo uname` instead of just `uname`?

Comment: @JeromeAnsia Actually, I've changed my mind - instead of trying to track down what's fiddling with `$PATH`, which might well be a needle in a haystack depending how much of a unique snowflake that server is, just change `uname` in your script to `/bin/uname`, so `$PATH` doesn't need to be accurate.

Comment: that's smart Shane, let me poke around with this solution instead!